# Error al hacer rake db:import:all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, firebird

estoy intentando realizar un rake db:import:all de una base de datos y obtengo el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando Firebird x64 SuperServer v2.5.9
Ruby v2.6.3
Rails v13.0.1
Mi sistema operativo es Osx high sierra

Comment: Por favor, recuerda que un texto vale mucho más que un pantallazo. Es fácilmente indexable por buscadores, si alguien tiene tu mismo problema puede llegar a esta pregunta sin problemas, le evitas el trabajo de escribir tu error a quienes puedan ayudarte, en mobiles carga mil veces más rápido, es fácilmente formateable, no se ve como un texto minúsculo en la pregunta, etc... Vamos, que no eres un usuario nuevo. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Tienes conflictos entre versiones de 32bits y 64bits.
Si te has asegurado que Firebird es x64, revisa que tu ruby también lo es con `ruby -v` (debería mostrar algo como `[x86_64-darwin18]`), aparte prueba a correr `gem pristine fb` por si la gema fue compilada referenciando a alguna antigua librería de 32 bits.